# How can I remove the empty string resulting from a split?

Tags: java

When I split a String :

```
A.B.C.
```

by `.`. I get 4 strings. The fourth being the white space. How can I remove that ?

```
String tokens[] = text.split("\\.");
    for(String token : tokens) {
        System.out.println("Token : " + token);
    }
```

Comment: Can I introduce you to Google's Guava lib... specifically Splitter? http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

Comment: @TwHelloInc Why not ? You can do this in an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If whitespace at the beginning or end is the problem, trim it off:

```
String tokens[] = text.trim().split("\\.");
```

Comment: It was as simple as this !

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the whitespace with a `replaceAll()` before your code.

```
text.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Comment: This will have some major side-effects.  Try it on this: `  .A B. C .  `

Answer (score -1):

Your String is A.B.C. so that whenever you split that it with `.` it will be give four substrings only. Even though you use `trim()` it will give four substrings. So try to remove last `.` and then split string. You will get proper output.